# How to access a dynamic variables?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have created dynamic variables in my tkinter project, but i can't access it, how i can do this?

```py
dict_ndfitemcostcategory = {}
for ndicc in range(2, 133):
    # self.neighborhood_details_item_cost_category_entry_2  - starting point
    dict_ndfitemcostcategory["self.neighborhood_details_item_cost_category_entry" + "_" + str(ndicc)] = tk.Text(self.frame, height=2, width=25, bg='alice blue', wrap=tk.WORD)
    dict_ndfitemcostcategory["self.neighborhood_details_item_cost_category_entry" + "_" + str(ndicc)].grid(row=ndicc, column=3, padx=5, pady = 4)
```

I tried to run:

```py
self.neighborhood_details_item_cost_category_entry_2.insert(tk.END, "asd")
```

But it looks like it cannot be found:
`AttributeError: 'Neighborhood_Details' object has no attribute 'dict_ndn'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't defining dynamic variables; you are only defining an ordinary `dict` that goes out of scope when the function returns. The dictionary *itself* should be an instance attribute, with the desired "dynamic" attributes as keys.

```
self.dict_ndfitemcostcategory = {}
for ndicc in range(2, 133):   
    key = "neighborhood_details_item_cost_category_entry" + "_" + str(ndicc)
    self.dict_ndfitemcostcategory[key] = tk.Text(self.frame, height=2, width=25, bg='alice blue', wrap=tk.WORD)
    self.dict_ndfitemcostcategory[key].grid(row=ndicc, column=3, padx=5, pady = 4)
```

Then

```
self.dict_ndfitemcostcategory["neighborhood_details_item_cost_category_entry_2"].insert(tk.END, "asd")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for exaplanation and solution! :)